# Speed up Cuda program

Tags: c++, cuda

Which part to change to speed up this code? And what exactly is code is doing?

```
__global_ void mat(Matrix a, Matrix b) 
{
   int[] tempData = new int[2];
   tempData[0] = threadIdx.x ;
   tempData[1] = blockIdx.x * blockDim;
   b.elements[tempData[1] + tempData[0]] = b.elements[tempData[1] + tempData[0]] * 5;
}
```

Comment: BTW parameter a is not used. You could indirectly speed up this code by combining this function call with the previous or next one (and multiply by 5 there) to reduce, how often b is read/written.

Answer (score 1):

If that is all the code in question, this is silliness:

```
int[] tempData = new int[2];
tempData[0] = threadIdx.x ;
tempData[1] = blockIdx.x * blockDim;
```

Just do this instead:

```
__global__ void mat(Matrix a, Matrix b) 
{

   int tempData_0 = threadIdx.x ;
   int tempData_1 = blockIdx.x * blockDim;
   b.elements[tempData_1 + tempData_0] = b.elements[tempData_1 + tempData_0] * 5;
}
```

The construct `tempdata[0] + tempdata[1]` is effectively creating the canonical CUDA 1D globally unique thread index:

```
int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
```

With that constructed index, then your main code is:

```
b.elements[idx] = b.elements[idx] * 5;
```

Which is taking the elements of a vector (or a matrix, where the rows or columns are stored contiguously) and multiplying them by 5.

Your code could probably be simplified more to make it easier to read, following the outline I have give you using `idx`, but those changes won't make a significant performance difference.  The compiler can figure out those kinds of transformations.